# Sharing only one window or part of a screen in Zoom

Tags: screen-sharing, zoom

The following link from a college refers to sharing part of the screen in Zoom  https://www.etsu.edu/helpdesk/documents/zoom-share-portion-of-screen.pdf

[image]

However when I click on "Share | Advanced Sharing Options" as follows:

[image]

There are no partial screen sharing options available:

[image]

So then - how can part of the screen or only one window be shared?

**Update**  When clicking directly on the green "Share" there are no options at all for customization - not any dialog or any buttons.

[image]

There is only this:

[image]

**Another update** OK the issue is that I had sometime in the past set up "Automatically share desktop" in *Prefences* . I'll make that an answer per @grg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I had sometime in the past set up "Automatically share desktop" in *Prefences* .  I had forgotten about having made that selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don’t click the arrow next to the share button — just click the green Share button itself.

‘Advanced’ doesn’t refer to the advanced options dialog, just the tab at the top of the normal window accessed by clicking Share.

Comment: Tried that a number of times: when clicking directly on the Share there is *no* dialog or options to customize the share.  I'll add a screenshot of it

Comment: Ah I see - I had set up "Automatically share" on options. I updated the question

Comment: @Stephen Ah good spot, feel free to leave as a separate answer

Comment: thx I guess the "good spot" is the glass half full version of "bad memory"

Comment: @Stephen I’m sure it’ll be useful for others, I didn’t know that setting existed so thanks for teaching me about it!